# Masters method with sqrt

Tags: algorithms, roots, recursive-algorithms

I was doing

> $$T(n)=4T(n/2)+n^3+\sqrt{n}$$

Without the square root, it is a basic example but with a square root there, I dont know what to do.

I think the 3rd parameter of the masters method  will be applied but I just dont know what to do with the square root.

As it is not in the form of

> $$T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n)$$

How should it be solved or should I use the tree method for this?

Comment: If you want to apply the Master theorem, take $a=4$, $b=2$, and $f(n) = n^3 +\sqrt{n}$. What is the issue?

Comment: So this means f(n)=n^3+√n and thus by the 3 parameter f(n)=delta (n^log↓b^a+e) time complexity will be t(n)=theta (n^3+√n)  am i right ?

Comment: I haven't checked your answer (hard to read without the formatting), but at first glance: **never** write $\Theta(n^3+\sqrt{n})$. This goes fundamentally against the $\Theta$ notation: $\sqrt{n}=o(n^3)$, don't include low-order terms in the $\Theta$.

Comment: Thanks for the help and in low order it is delta i know but what about when we find the time complexity our professor showed theta there was he wrong or i understood wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. My point was that writing $\Theta(n^3+\sqrt{n})$, or $\Theta(n^3+1)$, , or $\Theta(n^3+n^2)$, **makes no sense**. In the $\Theta$, you only keep the dominating term, $n^3$.

Comment: Otherwise, it's akin to saying "This house must be of the order of a million dollars *and two cents*."

Comment: Buckminster ? Thanks for the help and sry didnt fully grasp the quote .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you say that the equation is not of the form

$$T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n).$$

But it is, with $a=4,b=2,f(n)=n^3+\sqrt n$.

2) if you feel uncomfortable with $f(n)=n^3+\sqrt n$, as the equation is linear you can process the two terms separately, then join the two solutions.

3) the term $\sqrt n$ is of a lower order than $n^3$, so that you can neglect it without changing the asymptotics of the solution.